# Buscar elemento dentro de un array anidado JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, filtro, map, find

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un arreglo de objetos películas, cada uno de estos objetos tiene una propiedad géneros que es también un arreglo.
Me llega un genero especifico y tengo filtrar todas las películas que incluyan ese genero en su array de géneros.

Aquí el ejemplo:

```
const genero = 'accion'

  const  peliculas = [
      {
       id: 1,
       nombre:'uno',
       generos: [ 'accion','terror']
      },
       {
       id: 2,
       nombre:'dos',
       generos: [ 'terror']
      },
      {
       id:3,
       nombre:'tres',
       generos: [ 'accion', 'comedia']
      }
    ]
```

Deberia devolver

```
const peliculasFiltradas = [
  {
   id: 1,
   nombre:'uno',
   generos: [ 'accion','terror']
  },
   {
   id:3,
   nombre:'tres',
   generos: [ 'accion', 'comedia']
  }
]
```

Mi posible solucion :

```
const peliculasFiltradas = peliculas.filter(pelicula => {
  return pelicula.generos.includes(genero)
  })
```

Otra:

```
const peliculasFiltradas = peliculas.filter(pelicula => {
 return pelicula.generos.find(e => e === genero)
})
```

Eh intentado aplicar un filter al arreglo de películas y luego un find o includes a la propiedad géneros de cada una pero no logro resultados.
Alguien sabe como puedo resolverlo?
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Y qué has intentado o investigado? No pretendas que lo hagan todo por ti. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. También puedes leer [mcve]. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Hola si! te comento la solución que estaba intentando. Aplicar un filter al arreglo general y luego un find o un includes en su propiedad generos. Pero no me da resultado.

Comment: Puedes colocar eso que probaste?

Comment: recién edite la publicación

Comment: Porque no usas un ciclo sencillo, algo así https://jsfiddle.net/o3wdmsqu/

Comment: La primera solución que pones debería funcionarte ( cambiando `array` por `peliculas`). ¿Qué problema tienes?

Comment: Perdon fue un error de sintaxis de todos modos no me funciona

Comment: Como dice @Lobos solo poniendo peliculas en array ya funciona https://jsfiddle.net/u5d1426q/

Comment: Por favor coloca el resultado que estás obteniendo con la primer solución. Porque esa debería funciona. Agrega la salida

Comment: Hola me esta funcionando la solución del filter y también la del for que me paso @JosueVargas  Evidentemente mi problema esta en otro lado porque la lógica esta correcta. El problema debe estar en como me llegan los datos en la aplicación real

Comment: Gracias a todos por la ayuda!